# Stop swatches from loading images on product detail

Tags: magento2, product-images, swatches, color-swatches, size-weight-units

I have two swatches.. color and size. Is there a way to stop the size swatches from reloading the picture of the product and keep the color swatch working as usual?

Ty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Product images are changed by default js file `Magento_Swatches/js/swatch-renderer.js` on click of swatch options, below is the responsible function for it-

```
 /**
  * Load media gallery using ajax or json config.
  *
  * @param {String|undefined} eventName
  * @private
  */
    _loadMedia: function (eventName) {
            var $main = this.inProductList ?
                    this.element.parents('.product-item-info') :
                    this.element.parents('.column.main'),
                images;

            if (this.options.useAjax) {
                this._debouncedLoadProductMedia();
            }  else {
                images = this.options.jsonConfig.images[this.getProduct()];

                if (!images) {
                    images = this.options.mediaGalleryInitial;
                }

                this.updateBaseImage(images, $main, !this.inProductList, eventName);
            }
        }
```

There is another function `_OnClick: function ($this, $widget, eventName)` which is triggered on click of swatch option and this function calls function `_loadMedia` causes changes of product images.

So you need to do necessary amends in this file as per your requirement after copying it into your vendor/theme folder.

Comment: @gonazalo,  please give your feedback if you have tried it or not.

Comment: Thank you i think i know how to do it now! You saved me.

Comment: if you think my answer helped you then please mark it as answer please